# Typing only the number '3' into UITextfield crashes application in both simulator and on physical device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, ios-simulator

I have a set of six UITextfields, and for some strange reason whenever I type the number '3' and ONLY the number '3' the app crashes on both the simulator and on my physical device. The UITextField can accept any other sort of input just fine and can accept the number '3' as long as it is not the first character in the field. NOTE: I have a separate view controller with a text field that does NOT show this problem and can accept the number '3' as the first character in its UITextField without crashing. This behavior only manifests on this specific view controller.

I have broken my code down into its most simplistic form and the bug continues to manifest.

There is no error message in the debug console. I have spent hours scouring other forums and have yet to find a solution. This phenomenon is as bizarre as it is confusing- any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class AuthViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var authField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var authField2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var authField3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var authField4: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var authField5: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var authField6: UITextField!


    var keyboardHeight: Double = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        authField1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        authField1.delegate = self
        authField2.delegate = self
        authField3.delegate = self
        authField4.delegate = self
        authField5.delegate = self
        authField6.delegate = self

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardSlideUp(keyboardWillShowNotification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

        authField1.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @objc func keyboardSlideUp(keyboardWillShowNotification notification: Notification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
            keyboardHeight = Double(keyboardSize.height)
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        }
        print(keyboardHeight)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = -CGFloat(self.keyboardHeight)
        }
    }
```

[After pressing the number '3' on the keypad, the simulator/device simply freezes as is depicted in the image. For additional clarity, the vertical blinking blue line that would normally "pulsate" on an active textfield freezes as well as the highlighted '3' on the number pad freezing as well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xubtI.png)

Comment: Add a screenshot of the crash you're getting.

Comment: Screenshot attached. Apologies for not attaching before- new to stackoverflow and still learning etiquette for optimal communication.

Comment: Add logs of your crash

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no error log produced for this specific crash, making it all the more peculiar. I am increasingly beginning to suspect this may be a bug in the simulator?

Comment: You are setting the text field delegate but you haven't shown any delegate methods? Do you have any delegate methods.  Does it still hang if you comment `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?  It seems like a bad idea to mess with the layout in that function

Comment: You mention both a crash and a hang here. Which us it? If a crash, please provide the crash log. If a hang, please provide a spindump. What have you observed in debugging this with the debugger and/or Instruments?